# Add marker on map ANDROID

Tags: android, eclipse, api, google-maps-android-api-2

Good night, 
I have an application with a map in a swipe tab, but I want that map select a point and start at that point.

Thank you in advance.

Enclose JAVA:

```
public class Mapa extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa_3, container, false);

    return android;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    if (f != null)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

}

the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    tools:context=".Mapa" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add a marker to a map and set camera to look at it. Here is how you can achieve it(more info [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views)):

```
GoogleMap map;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapa_3, container, false);

    final LatLng position = new LatLng(MARKER_LATITUDE, MARKER_LONGITUDE);

    // marker
    map = ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(position)
        .title("Hello world"));

    // camera position
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0)
        {
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 14);
            map.animateCamera(cu);
            map.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
        }
    });
    return android;
}
```

Comment: i have error on: map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();  "Cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment"

Comment: I fixed the code, changed getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager().

Comment: Thks for the help, but i have a error on getSupportFragmentManager(): "The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Mapa"

Comment: Make sure you re-import from the support library.

Comment: Same error: The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Mapa

Comment: make your activity extend `FragmentActivity`

Comment: click ctrl+o to reimport everything